# How do I scale a single face without moving the whole object?

Tags: rendering

I'm a beginner on Blender. I am currently struggling to scale a single face without moving the whole object. I'm watching this Youtube tutorial and the guy just simply scaled the cylinder's upper face without affecting the other faces.

Here's the pic of the Blender tutorial vid where the guy just scaled the top face of the cylinder and only the top is scaled.
[image]

And here's a picture of me doing the same thing, although I'm following the same process, the outcome is different. The whole object is scaled and I only selected the top face. How and why is this happening? And How to solve it?
[image]

Comment: From your image, looks like you have proportional editing ON (The Blue Circle Icon on the top) Press O or click the circle tu turn it off

Comment: I turned off the edit proportion tool and the whole object is no longer moving, but the top face ends up as a very paper thin surface instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment, your original problem was that proportional editing was on, and so nearby vertices, beyond those you had selected, were also being affected by the resize operation.  To fix this, you can toggle out of proportional edit with <kbd>o</kbd> or click the associated icon.

Your next problem is probably a result of an extra extrusion.  If you extrude with <kbd>e</kbd> and then think better of it and click <kbd>Esc</kbd>, it will appear as if the extrusion operation has been aborted, but it hasn't.  You've extruded the face with some zero-width edges connecting the visible edges of your cylinder to the face.  When you resize the top face, those zero-width edges are stretched, leaving the visible edges unaffected and making the top look like a flate plate or disc.

Fixing this can be a little tough, but try the following:

- Undo any resize of the top, so it looks like the original cylinder.
- Make sure the object is selected and you're in edit mode.
- Select all the geometry with <kbd>a</kbd>.
- Perform a "merge" with <kbd>m</kbd> and select the bottom option "By Distance" from the pop-up.
- You should see a note in the status bar at the bottom that says "Removed xx vertices".  This means those zero-length edges were removed and their vertices merged together.
- Now, if you select the top face and resize, it will hopefully work as intended.

If that still doesn't work, you might want to just delete the cylinder object and try it again from the beginning.

Comment: It works! Thank you for the help, Imma keep this in mind whenever I encounter this problem again.